# Creating a Craigslist Anonymous Email Forwarding Program

Tags: php, mysql, imap, gmail-imap

The following program is intended to match incoming email aliases with those in the database, and forward the email to the right address, like Craigslist does.

I am now getting this error:

```
Error: [1] You must provide at least one recipient email address.
in anon-email.php at line number: sending the email
```

Here is the code:

```
$mailboxinfo = imap_mailboxmsginfo($connection);
$messageCount = $mailboxinfo->Nmsgs; //Number of emails in the inbox
for ($MID = 1; $MID <= $messageCount; $MID++)
  {
  $EmailHeaders = imap_headerinfo($connection, $MID); //Save all of the header information
  $Body = imap_qprint(imap_fetchbody($connection, $MID, 1)); //The body of the email to be forwarded

  $MessageSentToAllArray = $EmailHeaders->to; //Grab the “TO” header
  $MessageSentToAllObject = $MessageSentToAllArray[0];
  $MessageSentToMailbox = $MessageSentToAllObject->mailbox ."@". $MessageSentToAllObject->host; //Everything before and after the “@” of the recipient

  $MessageSentFromAllArray = $EmailHeaders->from; //Grab the “FROM” header
  $MessageSentFromAllObject = $MessageSentFromAllArray[0];
  $MessageSentFromMailbox = $MessageSentFromAllObject->mailbox ."@". $MessageSentFromAllObject->host; //Everything before and after the “@” of the sender
  $MessageSentFromName = $MessageSentFromAllObject->personal; //The name of the person who sent the email

  $toArray = searchRecipient($MessageSentToMailbox); //Find the correct person to send the email to
  if($toArray == FALSE) //If the alias they entered doesn’t exist…
    {
    $bounceback = 'Sorry the email in your message does not appear to be correct';
    /* Send a bounceback email */
    $mail = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php “mail()”
    $mail -> ContentType = 'text/plain'; //Plain email
    $mail -> IsHTML(false); //No HTML
    $the_body = wordWrap($bounceback, 70); //Word wrap to 70 characters for formatting
    $from_email_address = 'name@domain.com';
    $mail->AddReplyTo($from_email_address, "domain.Com");
    $mail->SetFrom($from_email_address, "domain.Com");
    $address = $MessageSentFromMailbox; //Who we’re sending the email to
    $mail->AddAddress($address, $MessageSentFromName);
    $mail->Subject = 'Request'; //Subject of the email
    $mail->Body = $the_body;
    if(!$mail->Send()) //If the mail fails, send to customError
      {
      customError(1, $mail->ErrorInfo, "anon-email.php", "sending the email");
      }
    }
  else //If the candidate address exists, forward on the email
    {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php “mail()”
    $mail -> ContentType = 'text/plain'; //Plain E-mail
    $mail -> IsHTML(FALSE); //No HTML
    $the_body = wordwrap($Body, 70); //Wordwrap for proper email formatting
    $from_email_address = "$MessageSentFromMailbox";
    $mail->AddReplyTo($from_email_address);
    $mail->SetFrom($from_email_address);
    $address = $toArray[1]; //Who we’re sending the email to
    $mail->AddAddress($address, $toArray[0]); //The name of the person we’re sending to
    $mail->Subject = $EmailHeaders->subject; //Subject of the email
    $mail->Body = ($the_body);
    if(!$mail->Send()) //If mail fails, go to the custom error
      {
      customError(1, $mail->ErrorInfo, "anon-email.php", "sending the email");
      }
    }
  /* Mark the email for deletion after processing */
  imap_delete($connection, $MID);
  }
  imap_expunge($connection); // Expunge processes all of the emails marked to be deleted
  imap_close($connection);

  function searchRecipient() // function to search the database for the real email
{
    global $MessageSentToMailbox; // bring in the alias email
    $email_addr = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM tbl WHERE source='$MessageSentToMailbox'"); // temp store of the real email
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($email_addr); //making temp store of data for use in program
    if(empty($row['email']))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    else  /* Else, return find the person's name and return both in an array */
    {
        $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE email = '$email_addr'"); // temp store of both queries from this function
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($results, $email_addr); //making temp store of data for use in program
        $name = $row['author'];  // taking the author data and naming its variable
        return array($name, $email_addr);  // this is the name and the real email address to be used in function call
    }
}

function customError($errno, $errstr, $file, $line)
{
    error_log("Error: [$errno] $errstr in $file at line number: $line",1, "name@domain.com","From: name@domain.com.com");   
    die();
}
```

Comment: Probably a silly question, but are you sure that $address is being populated properly?

Comment: I looked through the code and didn't see anything of why it wouldn't be.  Did you notice anything?

Comment: Oh, if it isn't it is supposed to send a bounce back.

Comment: I always figure it can't hurt to check that what you're actually passing in to the function is the same as what you think you're passing in to the function. There's nothing obviously wrong, but since you're generating the email from function calls, it can't hurt to double-check.

Comment: One thing I'd recommend is to trace the execution of your code, and check the output at each juncture. Something as simple as `print_r($var); exit();` is really useful to check intermediate program results.

Comment: Thank you Andrew and Halfer.  I really have to do this next time I work on a new script.  It would have saved me so much time!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the first thing I would try:
It would appear that your function searchRecipient isn't being passed a parameter.  Rather than use the global keyword, I would define it in your function call.  Also, mysql_fetch_array does not pass back an associative array, which is what you are using in your next step.  I would change that to mysql_fetch_assoc (it's the same thing essentially).  There are also a few other minor syntax corrections in this function.  Here are my proposed changes to that function.  I think this should fix your problem.  Or at least get you moving forward.

```
function searchRecipient($MessageSentToMailbox) // function to search the database for the real email
{

    $email_addr = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM tbl WHERE source='$MessageSentToMailbox'"); // temp store of the real email
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($email_addr); //making temp store of data for use in program
    if(empty($row['email']))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    else  /* Else, return find the person's name and return both in an array */
    {
        $email_addr = $row['email'];
        $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE email = '$email_addr'"); // temp store of both queries from this function
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results); //making temp store of data for use in program
        $name = $row['author'];  // taking the author data and naming its variable
        return array($name, $email_addr);  // this is the name and the real email address to be used in function call
    }
}
```

You could also combine this into one query and make it a little easier.  Here is that solution.

```
function searchRecipient($MessageSentToMailbox)
{
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT email, author FROM tbl WHERE source='$MessageSentToMailbox'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
    if(empty($row['email']) || empty($row['author'])) return false;
    return array($row['email'], $row['author']);
}
```

Comment: Alright, I'm on my phone at the moment rather than a computer, so it's hard to see enough code.  Let me get to the desk, and I'll finish taking a look at the rest of the code.  I stopped looking as soon as I saw that.

Comment: Two quick things that will help: 1) In my shortened function, I reversed the return values accidentally.  2) If that doesn't fix your issue, var_dump the toArray and let me know what you get.

Comment: I am so freaking happy!  We got it to work.  Thank you so much for your help.  I am screaming at the top of my lungs how happy I am.  3-4 weeks of work! Thank you, thank you, thank you.